# WSGI post-process cleanup

Tags: python-2.7, replication, mod-wsgi, pymongo, ming

I'm running a TurboGears app with mod_wsgi and apache, using pymongo wrapped with Ming for persistence. To failproof and scale my app I was interested in using mongo's support for replica sets through a pymongo [ReplicaSetConnection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/replica_set_connection.html).

However, as specified in the above links, one must call `close()` when done with every pymongo `ReplicaSetConnection` object, otherwise it will leave a bunch of zombie processes floating around (wtf pymongo). This sort of behavior isn't supported very well in Ming (it actually doesn't really support Replica Sets yet), but I managed to write a cleanup function that closes all pymongo connections.

Now I want to run my cleanup function on process cleanup for all my app processes. These have two basic entry points: mod_wsgi through apache and paster commands. It is no problem to add my cleanup to the paster commands, but is there a way to specify a cleanup function for wsgi processes?

If not, any other advice for setting this up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no guarantee your code will even be called as processes can just crash or be forcibly exited before it is called. With that caveat, read the mod_wsgi documentation about this specific issue:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/RegisteringCleanupCode

Comment: I believe this should be sufficient. My processes hang when I don't close the sessions, so I'm assuming the mentioned "background task" is in the main process. I'll confirm this here when I run some tests.

Comment: The cleanup function would be called in each WSGI process where you call atexit.register().

Comment: Isn't there something standard in WSGI itself for this?

Comment: In the standard for what in particular? Post request cleanup is covered in that document. For process wide cleanup on shutdown, no, the WSGI specification doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

TurboGears itself also provides the **shutdown** hook which can be registered using base_config.register_hook inside config/app_cfg.py.

The shutdown hook gets called whenever the process exists